# Can the openjdk 8 jvm use more than 4 cores?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've asked the question [on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630381/jvm-only-uses-4-cores?noredirect=1#comment1179691_630381) as well...

Can the openjdk 8 (on ubuntu) run more than 4 threads

(i.e.: use the 8 cores available) on a system?

Edit: I have 12 Thread objects which run simultaneously (they all produce output) but the linux top program indicates there are only 4 cores occupied with the java process (when scaling from 1 Thread to 2, 3 and 4 I didn't have this problem)...

Edit2: top output:

```
%Cpu(s): 41.8 us

6982 ubuntu    20   0 8766844   1.7g  18684 S 352.0  11.6  26:07.56 java
```

lscpu output:

```
CPU(s):                          8
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-7
Thread(s) per core:              2
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
```

Edit3:

```
            Agent[] agentz = new Agent[4]; //implements Runnable

            agentz[0] = new Agent(botMovez[0], playerIndex);

            for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

                agentz[i] = new Agent(botMovez[i], playerIndex, boardCopies[i - 1]);
            }

            Thread[] threadz = new Thread[4];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                threadz[i] = new Thread(agentz[i]);

                threadz[i].start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                try {

                    threadz[i].join();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

-> this code gets executed in a Runnable which is started like:

```
    (new Thread(new Calculator(this, performedMoves))).start();
```

Edit4:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test = new Test();

        TestAgent[] testAgentz = new TestAgent[8];

        Thread[] threadz = new Thread[8];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            testAgentz[i] = test.new TestAgent();

            threadz[i] = new Thread(testAgentz[i]);

            threadz[i].start();
        }
        
        System.out.println("waiting to join...");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

            try {
                threadz[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("unreachable code");

    }

    private class TestAgent implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

-> This code does occupy 800% cpu

So it must be either Spring boot or Tomcat...

I'm going to ask another question because this one is getting to cluttered...

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes, I have a program that has enough load for 12 threads but it only uses 4 i.e. 400 cpu (where 800 is available)

Comment: Well, I guess you need to ask the question differently. 1. Add the code that's starting those threads 2. How are you assessing the number of cores used by the program?

Comment: is your prgram using multiple threads? When testing on windows, the jvm uses all of my 8 cores. (simple test with loops in 16 seperate threads)

Comment: Does your CPU have 8 cores or 4 cores with Hyperthreading. Which CPU do you have?

Comment: I have a program that uses 12 Threads and a virtual machine with 8 cores, and the threads only run on 4 cores.

Comment: 8 cores with 2 threads per core (but I seem to use 400% of the available 800%) (top: %Cpu(s): 58.5 us -> 6982 ubuntu    20   0 8766844   1.7g  18684 S 352.0  11.6  26:07.56 java

Comment: You don't need to add details in comments. The field is made especially fiddly for that. Edit your question.

Comment: Could we have the code you use to start threads etc.? And to answer your question, yes openjdk 8 can use way more than 4 cores.

Comment: I only see 4 threads in your code?

Comment: I run the code 3 times

Comment: It's hard to understand the full code. What if you make a dummy program with 8 threads that just does `while (true)` per thread? Can you get to 800% then?

Comment: @Halfgaar: the code added (see last edit) does occupy 8 cores... so it's not an openjdk 8 issue...

Comment: @Halfgaar: if you make an answer out of it I'll approve it...

Answer (score -2):

I see the output of `lscpu` give 2 threads per core. You don't have an 8 core machine. Try running something like `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null` 8 times. Probably you sill don't go over 400%.

Comment: This doesn't match my experience. Typically virtual cpus count as full cpus for this kind of thing. Not saying this is wrong just suspect.

Comment: running that cat command doesn't increase the "%Cpu(s):  0.0 us" but the "0.0 sy" but, if run 5 times, the 5 different cat processes each get 100% cpu in the list